# How to refer to a DOM element inside a child component? [ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this Header component that has a number of Link Components inside it as shown below. I am rendering the components conditionally based on url path. I wanted to add a CSS class of 'active' to the appropriate link that which would let the users know which is the active link.

### Header.tsx

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from './Link';

export const Header: React.FC = () => {
  const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = React.useState<HTMLAnchorElement | null>(
    null
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    activeLink?.classList.add('active');

    return () => activeLink?.classList.remove('active');
  }, [activeLink]);

  return (
    <div className="ui secondary pointing menu">
      <div className="ui container">
        <Link href="/" className="item" setActiveLink={setActiveLink}>
          Accordion
        </Link>
        <Link href="/search" className="item" setActiveLink={setActiveLink}>
          WikiSearch
        </Link>
        <Link href="/translate" className="item" setActiveLink={setActiveLink}>
          Translate
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Link.tsx

```js
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  href: string;
  className: string;
  children: string;
  setActiveLink: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<HTMLAnchorElement | null>>;
};

export const Link: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { href, className, children, setActiveLink } = props;

  const onClick = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) return;

    setActiveLink(event.target as HTMLAnchorElement);
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState({}, '', href);
    const navEvent = new PopStateEvent('popstate');
    window.dispatchEvent(navEvent);
  };

  return (
    <a href={href} className={className} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </a>
  );
};
```

I tried to do implement it by using an activeLink state which would hold the active link and that works fine only once you click on some link but on the first render, there is no Link component that has the active class on it. I set the useState as null since I didn't know how to refer to the first Link Component.

Ideally, I want to initialize the activeLink state to the anchor element inside the first child Link Component. So that on first render, the first Link Component is the active Link by default.

In vanilla JS i could simply do something like

```
links = document.querySelector('a.item');
links.forEach(link => link.classList.remove('active'));
```

then supposing I have access to the active link dom element I could

```
activeLink.classList.add('active')
```

and I could just add the active class to the first anchor tag in html

```
<a href='something' class='active item'> some text </a>
```

So how would I implement the same in React?
Please suggest some ideas on how I should approach this or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why can't we use `window.location.pathname` in `Header.tsx`to fetch either `/` or `/search` etc and then assign the `active class` to the `Link` which has a matching `href` with this `pathname` ?

Comment: I feel like I am over complicating the logic as this feels like this should have a simple solution.

Comment: I think the solution i shared should solve the problem, as in case of a router, the URL should be the single source of truth.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Trying that out to see if it works.

Comment: @RohitKhanna Thanks man. Totally worked! I was trying to do the wrong thing. As you said, the URL should be the single source of truth.

Comment: Upvote if it helped ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Rohit I tried changing the activeLink state to storing currentPath as state and then later checking the href attribute and it worked out perfectly.

### Router.tsx

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from './Link';

export const Header: React.FC = () => {
  const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = React.useState(
    window.location.pathname
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const onURLChange = () => setCurrentPath(window.location.pathname);

    window.addEventListener('popstate', onURLChange);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('popstate', onURLChange);
  }, []);

  const getClassName = (path: string) => {
    return currentPath === path ? 'active item' : 'item';
  };

  return (
    <div className="ui secondary pointing menu">
      <div className="ui container">
        <Link href="/" className={getClassName('/')}>
          Accordion
        </Link>
        <Link href="/search" className={getClassName('/search')}>
          WikiSearch
        </Link>
        <Link href="/translate" className={getClassName('/translate')}>
          Translate
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Link.tsx

```js
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  href: string;
  className: string;
  children: string;
};

export const Link: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { href, className, children } = props;

  const onClick = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) return;

    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState({}, '', href);
    const navEvent = new PopStateEvent('popstate');
    window.dispatchEvent(navEvent);
  };

  return (
    <a href={href} className={className} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </a>
  );
};
```

This works like a charm.

Comment: Really feels like you're fighting React with the conditional class names. You might want to look into styled-components and passing props to achieve this design.