# How to add active on Click after map in child component? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I need to dynamically change the class to "active". I do this by checking indexes. The problem is that the active class changes IMMEDIATELY in all displayed li, and not in one particular one. This only happens when the logic is in the parent component, if you move the useState and onTypeActive to the child component everything works fine.

Parent component

```
  const [activeSyze, setActiveSyze] = useState(0);

  const onSyzeActive = (index) => {
  setActiveSyze(index);
      };

  return (
   <>
  {pizzaJson.map((item, index) => (
          <PizzaBlock
         key={item.id}
           onSyzeActive={(index) => onSyzeActive(index)}
          activeSyze={activeSyze}
           {...item}
        item={item}
        indexPizza={index}
           />
         ))}
      </>.
```

Child comp

```
 return (
  <ul>
      {sizes.map((size, index) => (
        <li
          key={index}
          onClick={() => onSyzeActive(index)}
          className={activeSyze === index ? "active" : ""}
        >
          {size} см.
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
     )
```

Comment: what is sizes props in child component ? @Anta

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: sizes is an array within an array. 
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "pizza 1,
    "sizes": [26, 30, 40],
  },
....
]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refer to a DOM element inside a child component? \[ReactJS\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65814208/how-to-refer-to-a-dom-element-inside-a-child-component-reactjs)

Comment: I don't have an error. I have product cards with certain parameters. The option for a specific map should be active when clicked, but instead the option becomes active in all maps, and not for one particular one.

Comment: I can't figure out why when the same logic is in a child component everything works)